# Передать данные из selectOneRadio - value в Backing bean в свойство типа List

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, xhtml, jsf

У меня в программе есть `ui:repeat` которым выводятся `h:selectionOneRadio` из `List`. Как передать данные выборов из `h:selectionOneRadio` в `List` внутри `Backing bean`

Comment: Не совсем так, у меня есть List<POJO> в Объекте листа хранятся данные для SelectOneRadio. И из листа с помощью репит выводятся данные в SelectOneRadio, мне нужен в конечном счете, Лист ответов.

Comment: 1) selectOneRadio вернет только одно значение (не может вернуть список), то есть, либо экземпляров selectOneRadio должно быть несколько, либо это должен быть не selectOneRadio. 2) если все же используется несколько selectOneRadio (1 POJO на 1 радиогруппу) то проще всего ему значение выбранного свойства добавить

Comment: у меня много SelectOneRadio которые выводятся в List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, `h:selectionOneRadio` используется для выбора 1 значения из нескольких. Значит, у вас Вас должен быть не просто список, а что-то вроде `List<List<POJO>>`. Так?

Тогда легче всего это сделать так:

Класс со значениями для выбора будет содержать и выбранное значение

```
public class ValueWrapper{

   //Список доступных значений
   protected List<String> valuesAvailable;
   //Выбранное значение
   protected String valueSelected;

   public ValueWrapper(){
   }

   //TODO добавить get и set методы

}
```

а в **xhtml** файле уже:

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{backing.mylist}">
   <h:selectOneRadio value="#{item.valueSelected}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{item.valuesAvailable}" />
   </h:selectOneRadio>
</ui:repeat>
```

**UPD**

Если же модифицировать POJO нельзя, то, у ui:repeat есть тег varStatus (у переменной статуса есть свойство index). 
Для значения так же создать класс обертки, типа:

```
public class ValueWrapper{
   //Выбранное значение
   protected String valueSelected;
   //TODO добавить get и set методы
}
```

после инициализации Вашего List создать List<Значения> точно такого же размера как List  и инициализировать.

типа

```
List<ValueVrapper> result = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < List<POJO>.size(); i++){
   result.add(new ValueWrapper());
}
```

а в **xhtml** файле уже:

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{backing.mylist}" varStatus="stat">
   <h:selectOneRadio value="#{backing.result.get(stat.index)}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{item.valuesAvailable}" />
   </h:selectOneRadio>
</ui:repeat>
```